# Проверка на вложенность меню

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Мне нужно чтобы в пункт меню, который содержит вложенный список, добавлялся значок. Я его реализовал через класс active. Но не знаю, как реализовать проверку на вложенность.

```css
nav {
  background-color: #49265c;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 4%;
  text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 22px 10px;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li ul,
nav ul li ul li {
  display: block;
}
nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0.95;
  background-color: #49265c;
  padding: 8px 0 20px 0;
  margin: 22px 0 0 -30px;
  max-width: 265px;
  display: none;
}
nav ul li ul li {
  padding: 5px 30px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1px;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-top: none !important;
}
nav ul li a.active:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
nav ul li:hover a {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover a,
nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover a {
  border-top: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">О компании</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="" class="active">Продукция</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Компрессоры ALBERT</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Стационарные 
компрессоры SEC</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Стационарные 
компрессоры SMARTRONIC</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Передвижные 
компрессоры</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Локомотивыне 
компрессоры</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Сервис</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Дилеры</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Доставка</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Контакт</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">4</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так, например:

```
$( "li" ).has( "ul" ).children('a').addClass('active');
```

Код:

```js
$( "li" ).has( "ul" ).children('a').addClass('active');
```

```css
nav {
  background-color: #49265c;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 4%;
  text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 22px 10px;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li ul,
nav ul li ul li {
  display: block;
}
nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0.95;
  background-color: #49265c;
  padding: 8px 0 20px 0;
  margin: 22px 0 0 -30px;
  max-width: 265px;
  display: none;
}
nav ul li ul li {
  padding: 5px 30px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1px;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-top: none !important;
}
nav ul li a.active:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
nav ul li:hover a {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover a,
nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover a {
  border-top: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">О компании</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Продукция</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Компрессоры ALBERT</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Стационарные 
компрессоры SEC</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Стационарные 
компрессоры SMARTRONIC</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Передвижные 
компрессоры</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Локомотивыне 
компрессоры</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Сервис</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Дилеры</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Доставка</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Контакт</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">4</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$( "li" ).has( "ul" ).children('a').addClass('active');` - наверное, лучше так

Comment: @Igor, точно! Спасибо!